# Timeline slider being compressed when adding elements

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to built a Timeline with a slider, where you can have more elements hidden, and when clicking a button, it will slide and reveal the hidden elements. The problem is when I add more elements, it shirinks the others to fit the div, but I need it to keep the elements that pass the div edge hidden, and I can reveal them with a horizontal scrollbar or clicking a button.

Can anyone help me??

Here is the code I have so far, if you want to see the the problem just add more items to the list.

https://codepen.io/Arthur_Oliveira/pen/GRKNGBb

```css
.timeline-background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.list-items {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.list-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-items li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.list-item li:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 78px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: -13px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item li:first-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item .active {
}

.list-items li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #D9D9D9;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-items li.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 3px solid #FF04FF;
  background-color: #FF04FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:first-child:after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-items li:after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-item ul .actived:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF04FF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center timeline-background">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="list-items">
            <ul class="d-flex d-xl-flex justify-content-center align-items-center justify-content-xl-center">
                <li class="active"><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
              
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item">
            <ul>
                <li class="d-flex d-sm-flex d-md-flex d-lg-flex d-xl-flex justify-content-center align-items-center justify-content-sm-center align-items-sm-center justify-content-md-center align-items-md-center actived" href="#list1"><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i></li>
                <li class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><a class="item" href="#"></a><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE::
I changed the class list-items to:

```css
.timeline-background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.list-items {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 86px;
  max-width: 440px;
}



.list-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-items li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.list-item li:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 78px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: -13px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item li:first-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item .active {
}

.list-items li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #D9D9D9;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-items li.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 3px solid #FF04FF;
  background-color: #FF04FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:first-child:after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-items li:after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-item ul .actived:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF04FF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center timeline-background">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <section class="list-items">
            <ul class="dots">
                <li class="active"><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <div class="list-item">
            <ul>
                <li class="d-flex d-sm-flex d-md-flex d-lg-flex d-xl-flex justify-content-center align-items-center justify-content-sm-center align-items-sm-center justify-content-md-center align-items-md-center actived" href="#list1"><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i></li>
                <li class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><a class="item" href="#"></a><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now it breaks the line when reaching the div edge!

Comment: You are describing something that will require javascript functionality, some special layout styling, and more UI elements. I recommend breaking this down to smaller individual issues and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo Can't it be done only with CSS or SCSS, to solve the problem when reaches the div edge, and it get compress or break the lin, but instead to get inside the div edge, like there was a tunnel, so it will not be visible?

Comment: Give a fixed value for width and `overflow: auto`. Your question is asking for more than that though.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo I've tryed that too, but it`s still the same! Yeah, I didn't explained too well, sorry, I'll rewrite the question late!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much who tried to help, I really appreciate!
I'm posting here how I solved this!
From the question text, you can compare the codes where I was stuck to the final code here.
What I did was to add the `backpage` class, and set a width to it with overflow hidden and position absolute, than I change `list-items` class position to absolute and also set a fixed width to it, than I just adjust the elements position on screen!!

Here the final Code:

```css
.timeline-background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.backpage {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 450px;
}

.list-items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2000px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.list-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-items li {
  position: relative;
}

.list-item li:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: -13px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item li:first-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item .active {
}

.list-items li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #D9D9D9;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-items li.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 3px solid #FF04FF;
  background-color: #FF04FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-items li:not(:last-child):after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-items li:first-child:before {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: -53px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-items li:last-child:after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-item ul .actived:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF04FF;
}

.list-item ul .actived {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.dots {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex d-xl-flex justify-content-center justify-content-xl-center timeline-background">
    <div class="backpage">
        <section class="list-items">
            <ul class="dots">
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <ul>
            <li class="d-flex d-sm-flex d-md-flex d-lg-flex d-xl-flex justify-content-center align-items-center justify-content-sm-center align-items-sm-center justify-content-md-center align-items-md-center" href="#list1"><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i></li>
            <li class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><a class="item" href="#"></a><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, Thanks so Much!!